# Problems with Simple Exponential Smoothing with Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have some problems constructing the forecast with the simple exponential Simple Exponential Smoothing. The forecast value is not to sync and way off. I am very new to this thus any form of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I had followed the following link:
https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/how-to-build-exponential-smoothing-models-using-python-simple-exponential-smoothing-holt-and-da371189e1a1

This is how my graph looks like before forecasting:
https://i.ibb.co/8KK4Q2R/1.png

After:
https://i.ibb.co/sCCbrMm/3.png
https://i.ibb.co/kqjWFzM/4.png

The forecasting does not seem to work, below are my codes

```
import datetime
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt

data = athlete_win_summer_df.groupby(['Year']).agg('count')['Medal']
data
```

```
data.plot.line(x = 'Year', 
             y = 'Medal',figsize=(20,8))

from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt


fit1 = SimpleExpSmoothing(saledata).fit(smoothing_level=0.2,optimized=False)
fit1.fittedvalues.plot(marker='o',  color='blue')

fcast1 = fit1.forecast(12).rename(r'$\alpha=0.2$')
# plot
fcast1.plot(marker='o', color='blue', legend=True)
```

Have I done something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, how did you create "saledata"?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem,

Turns out I had to fix the time as the index for it to work :)